# Android camera - taken picture inconsistent with preview

Tags: android, camera, commonsware-cwac

I'm having an issue with the camera on Android, basically when I take a photo with the Camera class, the taken output picture actually shows more than the preview. The best way to put it would be the preview is cropped. How would I fix this?

I've run the app on Samsung Galaxy S4, Samsung Galaxy S3, HTC One M8 and Nexus One and all exhibit this same issue. (All running Android 4.0 ICS)

The camera preview is full screen in an Activity with no Action Bar and the status bar hidden.

The camera i'm trying to create is portrait so I've set displayOrientation to 90.

The code I use for determining preview size and output photo size is as follows (I believe the problem is most likely here somewhere):

```
public static Camera.Size getBestAspectPreviewSize(int displayOrientation,
                                                 int width,
                                                 int height,
                                                 Camera.Parameters parameters,
                                                 double closeEnough) {
double targetRatio=(double)width / height;
Camera.Size optimalSize=null;
double minDiff=Double.MAX_VALUE;

if (displayOrientation == 90 || displayOrientation == 270) {
  targetRatio=(double)height / width;
}

List<Size> sizes=parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();

Collections.sort(sizes,
                 Collections.reverseOrder(new SizeComparator()));

for (Size size : sizes) {
  double ratio=(double)size.width / size.height;

  if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) < minDiff) {
    optimalSize=size;
    minDiff=Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio);
  }

  if (minDiff < closeEnough) {
    break;
  }
}

return(optimalSize);
}


 public static Camera.Size getLargestPictureSize(CameraHost host,
                                              Camera.Parameters parameters,
                                              boolean enforceProfile) {
Camera.Size result=null;

for (Camera.Size size : parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes()) {

  // android.util.Log.d("CWAC-Camera",
  // String.format("%d x %d", size.width, size.height));

  if (!enforceProfile
      || (size.height <= host.getDeviceProfile()
                             .getMaxPictureHeight() && size.height >= host.getDeviceProfile()
                                                                          .getMinPictureHeight())) {
    if (result == null) {
      result=size;
    }
    else {
      int resultArea=result.width * result.height;
      int newArea=size.width * size.height;

      if (newArea > resultArea) {
        result=size;
      }
    }
  }
}

if (result == null && enforceProfile) {
  result=getLargestPictureSize(host, parameters, false);
}

return(result);
 }
```

Size comparator class:

```
private static class SizeComparator implements
  Comparator<Camera.Size> {
@Override
public int compare(Size lhs, Size rhs) {
  int left=lhs.width * lhs.height;
  int right=rhs.width * rhs.height;

  if (left < right) {
    return(-1);
  }
  else if (left > right) {
    return(1);
  }

  return(0);
}
}
```

This is using cwac-camera and using SimpleCameraHost with no changes.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would I fix this?

If you are using the full-bleed preview, the preview will be cropped in most cases, as the aspect ratio of the `CameraView` is unlikely to match the aspect ratio of the preview frames.

Quoting [the documentation](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera#supporting-full-bleed-preview):

> The original default behavior of `CameraFragment` and `CameraView` was to show the entire
>   preview, as supplied by the underlying `Camera` API. Since the aspect ratio of
>   the preview frames may be different than the aspect ratio of the `CameraView`,
>   this results in a "letterbox" effect, where the background will show through on
>   one axis on the sides.
>
> The new default behavior is to completely fill the `CameraView`, at the cost of
>   cropping off some of the actual preview frame, what is known as "full-bleed preview"
>   (stealing some terminology from the world of print media).
>
> To control this behavior:
>
> - Have your `CameraHost`
>     return `true` or `false` from `useFullBleedPreview()`
> - Or, call `useFullBleedPreview()`
>     on your `SimpleCameraHost.Builder`, passing in a `boolean` value to use by default.
>
> Note that the pictures and videos taken by this library are unaffected by
>   `useFullBleedPreview()`. Hence, if `useFullBleedPreview()` returns `true`, the
>   picture or video may contain additional content on the edges that was not
>   visible in the preview.

Comment: I've made useFullBleedPreview() return false , but I still have the same issue. Do you think this has something to do with zoom? Or is it because the preview is cropped and the taken picture isn't?

Comment: @DavidXu: If your preview did not change, then something is wrong -- either you aren't disabling full-bleed preview properly, or there is a bug in the library.

Comment: I've overridden useFullBleedPreview() in my custom CameraHost to return false, shouldn't this be sufficient?

Comment: @DavidXu: It should be. Is your preview showing up "letterboxed" (i.e., white bars one one side)?

Comment: No it's not. Screen is completely filled with the camera preview. Running on Galaxy S4 with 4.0 ICS.

Comment: @DavidXu: Download the demo project and try it there. If you can reproduce the problem with the demo project, file an issue. If the demo project works properly once you change the full-bleed preview setting, then there's something else going wrong with your project.

Comment: Okay just tested the cwac-camera demo. Same issue. There's a gap around the objects I took a photo of in the saved image that wasn't in the preview. Furthermore, the front camera preview in the cwac-demo is squished down vertically.

Comment: @DavidXu: Well, the preview is supposed to be "squished down vertically" with full-bleed preview off, if that is what makes the aspect ratios work. My understanding was that your preview had not changed when you applied this to your own app. Beyond that, my assumption is that this is a function of the underlying `Camera` logic. All I am doing is requesting the preview and the picture, and with full-bleed preview off, I am not doing anything to crop either the preview or the picture.

Comment: I took a photo with fullBleedPreview = false and fullBleedPreview = true with the demo cwac-camera project. I aligned 2 iPhones next to each other and put pens above, aligning the edge of the preview with the edges of the 2 iPhones and the pens. When I took the photo and looked at the output, there is more in the image than in the preview. Both with fullBleedPreview = false and true. 

Taken picture looks like this: http://puu.sh/9iYNq/a57a8cfc89.png whereas the edges should be aligned with the phones.

Comment: @DavidXu: My point is that this may have nothing to do with my library. I mean, I get the same results with the Camera app on my Nexus 4 -- the picture has more than the preview. Based on the nature of what I see with the Camera app, the aspect ratios are different (preview vs. picture), so you will get different results by definition. You are welcome to crop the picture, as you see fit, based upon the aspect ratio you are using for the preview, if you want. My library does not do that for you automatically (feel free to file an enhancement request for that if you want).

Comment: @DavidXu: My answer was simply trying to ensure that you were "comparing apples with apples", and not having the full-bleed cropping be the source of your difficulty.

Comment: I see - I'll probably end up cropping the picture myself then, I also tested the native camera app on my Galaxy S4 and it works as expected, so i'm not sure exactly where the issue is :)

Comment: @DavidXu: Measure the aspect ratios of the preview and the picture. The picture's ratio can be calculated from the resulting image file; the preview's ratio would need to be measured using a ruler (if it's not full-screen). If those ratios are identical, then the preview will match the picture, and that was either achieved by cropping or happening to choose picture and preview sizes that had the same ratio. If the ratios are not identical, then by definition, either the picture or the preview will show something the other does not.

Comment: @DavidXu: You are certainly welcome to consider keeping the same aspect ratio as a criterion in choosing your picture and preview sizes. If you choose ones that have the same ratio, the preview and picture should match in what they show (with full-bleed preview off, anyway). However, there is no requirement of device manufacturers to offer a good preview size and a good picture size that happen to have the same aspect ratio.

Comment: Thanks for everything, I've solved it by cropping to the aspect ratio of the output image. Works perfectly now! Great library by the way!

Comment: @DavidXu: I'm glad that you got it working to your satistfaction!